# What is optimal algorithm to check if a given integer is equal to sum of two elements of an int array?

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def check_set(S, k):    
S2 = k - S
set_from_S2=set(S2.flatten())
for x in S:    
    if(x in set_from_S2):    
        return True
return False
```

I have a given integer k. I want to check if k is equal to sum of two element of array S.

```
S = np.array([1,2,3,4])
k = 8
```

It should return `False` in this case because there are no two elements of S having sum of 8. The above code work like `8 = 4 + 4` so it returned `True`

I can't find an algorithm to solve this problem with complexity of `O(n)`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I tried running it, it really ran fast. You can see [this image](https://i.imgur.com/jOp9CaE.png)

Answer (score 6):

You have to account for multiple instances of the same item, so set is not good choice here.

Instead you can exploit dictionary with `value_field = number_of_keys` (as variant - `from collections import Counter`)

```
A = [3,1,2,3,4]
Cntr = {}
for x in A:
    if x in Cntr:
        Cntr[x] += 1
    else:
        Cntr[x] = 1

#k = 11
k = 8
ans = False
for x in A:
    if (k-x) in Cntr:
        if k == 2 * x:
            if Cntr[k-x] > 1:
                ans = True
                break
        else:
            ans = True
            break
print(ans)
```

Returns True for k=5,6 (I added one more 3) and False for k=8,11

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally understood. This is what I'm trying to find. Thank you again

Answer (score 4):

Adding onto MBo's answer.

"Optimal" can be an ambiguous term in terms of algorithmics, as there is often a compromise between how fast the algorithm runs and how memory-efficient it is. Sometimes we may also be interested in either worst-case resource consumption or in average resource consumption. We'll loop at worst-case here because it's simpler and roughly equivalent to average in our scenario.

Let's call `n` the length of our array, and let's consider 3 examples.

**Example 1**

We start with a very naive algorithm for our problem, with two nested loops that iterate over the array, and check for every two items of different indices if they sum to the target number.

- Time complexity: worst-case scenario (where the answer is `False` or where it's `True` but that we find it on the last pair of items we check) has `n^2` loop iterations. If you're familiar with the big-O notation, we'll say the algorithm's time complexity is `O(n^2)`, which basically means that in terms of our input size `n`, the time it takes to solve the algorithm grows more or less like `n^2` with multiplicative factor (well, technically the notation means "*at most like* `n^2` with a multiplicative factor, but it's a generalized abuse of language to use it as "more or less like" instead).
- Space complexity (memory consumption): we only store an array, plus a fixed set of objects whose sizes do not depend on `n` (everything Python needs to run, the call stack, maybe two iterators and/or some temporary variables). The part of the memory consumption that grows with `n` is therefore just the size of the array, which is `n` times the amount of memory required to store an integer in an array (let's call that `sizeof(int)`).

Conclusion: Time is `O(n^2)`, Memory is `n*sizeof(int)` (`+O(1)`, that is, up to an additional constant factor, which doesn't matter to us, and which we'll ignore from now on).

**Example 2**

Let's consider the algorithm in MBo's answer.

- Time complexity: much, much better than in Example 1. We start by creating a dictionary. This is done in a loop over `n`. Setting keys in a dictionary is a constant-time operation in proper conditions, so that the time taken by each step of that first loop does not depend on `n`. Therefore, for now we've used `O(n)` in terms of time complexity. Now we only have one remaining loop over `n`. The time spent accessing elements our dictionary is independent of `n`, so once again, the total complexity is `O(n)`. Combining our two loops together, since they both grow like `n` up to a multiplicative factor, so does their sum (up to a different multiplicative factor). Total: `O(n)`.
- Memory: Basically the same as before, plus a dictionary of `n` elements. For the sake of simplicity, let's consider that these elements are integers (we could have used booleans), and forget about some of the aspects of dictionaries to only count the size used to store the keys and the values. There are `n` integer keys and `n` integer values to store, which uses `2*n*sizeof(int)` in terms of memory. Add to that what we had before and we have a total of `3*n*sizeof(int)`.

Conclusion: Time is `O(n)`, Memory is `3*n*sizeof(int)`. The algorithm is considerably faster when `n` grows, but uses three times more memory than example 1. In some weird scenarios where almost no memory is available (embedded systems maybe), this `3*n*sizeof(int)` might simply be too much, and you might not be able to use this algorithm (admittedly, it's probably never going to be a real issue).

**Example 3**

Can we find a trade-off between Example 1 and Example 2?

One way to do that is to replicate the same kind of nested loop structure as in Example 1, but with some pre-processing to replace the inner loop with something faster. To do that, we sort the initial array, in place. Done with [well-chosen algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Memory_usage_patterns_and_index_sorting), this has a time-complexity of `O(n*log(n))` and negligible memory usage.

Once we have sorted our array, we write our outer loop (which is a regular loop over the whole array), and then inside that outer loop, use dichotomy to search for the number we're missing to reach our target `k`. This dichotomy approach would have a memory consumption of `O(log(n))`, and its time complexity would be `O(log(n))` as well.

- Time complexity: The pre-processing sort is `O(n*log(n))`. Then in the main part of the algorithm, we have `n` calls to our `O(log(n))` dichotomy search, which totals to `O(n*log(n))`. So, overall, `O(n*log(n))`.
- Memory: Ignoring the constant parts, we have the memory for our array (`n*sizeof(int)`) plus the memory for our call stack in the dichotomy search (`O(log(n))`). Total: `n*sizeof(int) + O(log(n))`.

Conclusion: Time is `O(n*log(n))`, Memory is `n*sizeof(int) + O(log(n))`. Memory is almost as small as in Example 1. Time complexity is slightly more than in Example 2. In scenarios where the Example 2 cannot be used because we lack memory, the next best thing in terms of speed would realistically be Example 3, which is almost as fast as Example 2 and probably has enough room to run if the very slow Example 1 does.

**Overall conclusion**

This answer was just to show that "optimal" is context-dependent in algorithmics. It's very unlikely that in this particular example, one would choose to implement Example 3. In general, you'd see either Example 1 if `n` is so small that one would choose whatever is simplest to design and fastest to code, or Example 2 if `n` is a bit larger and we want speed. But if you look at the wikipedia page I linked for sorting algorithms, you'll see that none of them is best at everything. They all have scenarios where they could be replaced with something better.

Comment: Change `O(log(n))` to `O(n*log(n))` in example 3.